# Gradle compiling old project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

i am using android studio 0.9.2. I copied project folder(all folders projectname->.gradle,.idea,app,build,gradle and all files placed in this level)  and renamed it and then in android studio i goto FILE-> CLOSE which close current opened project. Now i open again the project which i have copied. When i make some changes in code its not effecting compiler or debugger. I have debugged my code and found that my change in code does not take affect.

I have tried FILE->INVALIDATE CACHE AND RESTART and then check again but no luck. I have also closed my android studio and run it again but still i am facing same issue

I think its compiling old project which is last opened project.

Any help will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning the project. There are three ways to achieve that:

- via Menu: Build -> Clean Project
- via gradle run `gradlew clean`
- delete all the build directories in your project/modules

After that compile your project again (e.g. with the green play button) and you should be done.

Comment: thanks, it solve my problem. i have close android studio and then delete build directories and then open android studio. now its working f9

Answer (score 1):

I have a question. Is your gradle setting is in offline mode? Try turning it to online mode.

Also, just to add to above answer, Do you have any gradle dependencies with other project?

If so, also try cleaning those archives from your project folder within .m2 (maven) folder.

Comment: and how to turn gradle on online mode

Comment: can u just tell me one thing? why gradle settings is configures with one project? and if i copy full files why those gradle settings are configured with last project?

Comment: File->Settings. Select Gradle option and make sure the Globle Gradle setting is not tuned on for Offline work

Comment: Another question, how are you sure that it is reffering old code and not the current code? Have your tries deleting the build folder and it is still happening?  If so, post step by step on what solutions you tried in order. Also post the portion of the code which you see is not being reflected in your apk

Comment: "why gradle settings is configures with one project? and if i copy full files why those gradle settings are configured with last project?" not sure I understand what do you want to ask. If your notion is that project in gradle == project in eclipse then it is incorrect. 

   Also when you say you copy full files of project you are definitely copying the gradle settings. I suggest you do some reading by yourself on Android studio. If you still find issue, raise it with the studio team

Comment: can u recommend me how to copy project with new gradle settings?